# Need help adjusting changeImage js code

Tags: javascript

I'm a js beginner and I need some help to clean this code up. It's a changeImage situation, where I'm showing a check box with images rather than with an actual form check box. So the user can click an empty check box and the click changes the image to a check mark. And they can click again to unchecked. That all works, but this is the issue.

After you click one of the check box images, you then have to click twice to get another check box image to change. I'd like it to be a smooth, one click situation and I don't know what's preventing that. Here's a snippet of the code I'm using -

```
var newsrc = "img/checked.gif";

function changeImage() {
    if(newsrc == "img/checked.gif") {
        document.images["challenge"].src = "img/checked.gif";
        document.images["challenge"].alt = "Completed";
        newsrc = "img/checkBox.gif";
    } else {
        document.images["challenge"].src = "img/checkBox.gif";
        document.images["challenge"].alt = "Unfinished";
        newsrc = "img/checked.gif";
    }
}

function changeImage2() {
    if(newsrc == "img/checked.gif") {
        document.images["goal1"].src = "img/checked.gif";
        document.images["goal1"].alt = "Completed";
        newsrc = "img/checkBox.gif";
    } else {
        document.images["goal1"].src = "img/checkBox.gif";
        document.images["goal1"].alt = "Unfinished";
        newsrc = "img/checked.gif";
    }
}
```

There are six images in all in the script. I'm just showing the first two. Any help you can give would be great.

Comment: What about pre-loading the images on start-up then switching in between those images ?

Comment: @Vincent Piel - Do you think it's just a matter of the image not being loaded? Even after I've clicked through the images several times, they still need a double click to change. They're loaded by that point, right?

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that all of the functions are sharing the same `newsrc` variable and when you click one the others think they have been clicked as well.

You might be better off writing a single function which toggles the src and calling that function when any item is clicked.

Something like:

```
function toggleImage(clickedImage){
    var checkedSrc='img/checked.gif';
    var currentSrc=clickedImage.src;
    if(currentSrc.indexOf(checkedSrc) ==  currentSrc.length-checkedSrc.length){
        clickedImage.src='img/checkBox.gif';
        clickedImage.alt='Unfinished';
    }else{
        clickedImage.src='img/checked.gif';
        clickedImage.alt='Complete';
    }
}
```

And in your html

```
<img id="whatever_1" src="img/checkBox.gif" alt="Unfinished" onclick="toggleImage(this)" />
<img id="whatever_2" src="img/checkBox.gif" alt="Unfinished" onclick="toggleImage(this)" />
<img id="whatever_3" src="img/checkBox.gif" alt="Unfinished" onclick="toggleImage(this)" />
```

Comment: thanks for the response. that worked half way. it stopped the double clicking I was experiencing but it doesn't toggle the image back and fourth. It just changes the image once and stops. I tried swapping the off and on states in the code but it doesn't help. any thoughts?

Comment: OK what is happening is that the browser is completing the src attribute, making it an absolute address (adding in the http://yoursite.domain/folder/ bit) so the conditional test was never returning `true`, I've edited my answer so that we are testing to see that the image adress is at the end of the source attribute